# Unable to run virtualbox after fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: virtualbox

On a fresh install (not an upgrade from 17.04) I am not able to install /run virtualbox. I get the following error message when I run virtualbox:

```
tim@africantiger:~/Downloads$ virtualbox
VirtualBox: supR3HardenedMainGetTrustedMain: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox.so",) failed: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried satisfying all the libQt5* dependencies but eventually I get stuck on the following:

```
tim@africantiger:/usr/lib/virtualbox$ virtualbox 
Qt FATAL: This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".
```

Not sure how to proceed -- help!

Comment: How did you install virtualbox ?

Comment: I downloaded virtualbox-5.2_5.2.0-118431_Ubuntu_zesty_amd64.deb from virtualbox.org (there is no version for artful aardvark) and then did sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.2_5.2.0-118431_Ubuntu_zesty_amd64.deb

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt -f install` ?

Comment: yes i did (for no good reason except that i know if fixes broken installs).

Comment: You will probably have to install from the ubuntu repositores (remove what you installed first) and wait for 5.2 to be packaged. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=virtualbox

Comment: I also installed from the ubuntu repositories but that also did not work.

Comment: If the ubuntu repository does not work, file a bug report. We would need more information from you than a statement that it did not work. What did you do and what error message did yo get.

Comment: I did the following:

Comment: I did the following: 1) sudo apt remove virtualbox virtualbox-5.2  2)rm -rf /usr/lib/virtualbox  3) Using Ubuntu Software installed virtualbox 4) when I run virtualbox  I get `VirtualBox: supR3HardenedVerifyFileInternal: Failed to open "/usr/lib/virtualbox/VMMR0.r0": No such file or directory (2)`

Comment: According to https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=39951 , you will have to file a bug report with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. [This is my question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044292/virtualbox-will-not-install-on-fresh-copy-of-ubuntu-18-04/1045482#1045482), but what I did to fix the problem when I got to the xcb error was:

1. based on the output of `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so`:
2. `sudo apt install libxcb-xinerama0*`
3. `sudo apt install --reinstall libxcb-xinerama0*`